# fwrite duplicate file when saving to server

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to save data into a file using fwrite, the problem is that it is creating a second file with the same file name, and the data is saved to the second file and not the original.

It works under Windows localhost, Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.6 (no second file), but not on live server running Linux and PHP 5.4.42.

**edit.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var pageName = "<?php echo $pageName; ?> "; 
    $('#save').click(function(e) {  
     e.preventDefault();
       var content = $('#content').html(); 
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'includes/readInput.php',
                 data: {
                      content: content,
                      pageName: pageName,
                     }
                    }).done(
                        function(data){   
                       }
                  );
          });             
     });

readInput.php.
// Receive post variable s from "admin/ edit.php"
$content = $_POST['content'];
$pageName = $_POST['pageName'];
$dirPath= "../content/";
file_put_contents($dirPath.$pageName,$content);
```

Comment: did you try FILE_APPEND flag for file_put_contents?

Comment: Tried FILE_APPEND but didn't work, still getting duplicate file, but thanks for the suggestion, didn't think of that.

Comment: i have a small hunch that it doesn't duplicate anything, file_put_contents -by default- will overwrite the file, do me a small favore and tell me what is the creation date/time for both files plus the last modified date for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file where the data will be stored with the "a" from append flag this will result to write at the end of the file content:

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'a');
fwrite($file, 'new content');
```

Then you file will be stored with old content and "new content" the the end.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need the whole file to be overwritten. I have also used 'w' and 'w+' and 'wb'